# Validation in onBlur event in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, onblur

I have a long question. So basically, I have a text box which if filled with API call and as a default, it is read-only. What users can do is click on the textbox and change it. Then if the user clicks outside, the value is updated. So here is my input component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const InputPrice = ({ mainPricePosts, handleChange, onFocus }) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  function handleClick() {
    if (disabled === true) {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        className="price_coefficient_input"
        defaultValue={mainPricePosts}
        onBlur={(e) => {
          setDisabled(true);
          handleChange(mainPricePosts, e.target.value);
        }}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        readOnly={disabled}
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </>
  );
};

InputPrice.propTypes = {
  mainPricePosts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default InputPrice;
```

So, handleChange is in the parent component of this input component, which is basically:

```
const handleChange = (mainPricePosts, value) => {
    fetchIndividualPosts({ mainPricePosts, value });
  };
```

What I am trying to do is adding validation into this field. So, the textbox should only number and there should be at most 4 numbers after a comma such as **4.4569** So could you give me any idea how I can do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a more advanced way, checkout below codesandbox Link.

**Link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/formvalidation-y3qm7?file=/src/App.js

```
 <Form.Control
            type="number"
            className="price_coefficient_input"
            defaultValue={mainPricePosts}
            onBlur={(e) => {
              setDisabled(true);
              e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(4);
              handleChange(mainPricePosts, e.target.value);
            }}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            readOnly={disabled}
            onClick={handleClick}
          />
```